How are contacts from different channels charged in SF Marketing Cloud's pricing model?
I appreciate there is a documentation about Contact Definition and Count Determination in SFMC. There is also a reference for billing - the Contact Counts Report that can be created in Analytics Builder > Reports.
Having said that, I am still wondering how will my contacts in SFMC be charged considering:

I have X contacts with Email Address only (they are used for email marketing)
I will add Mobile Number for Y contacts (all these Y will be merged during the import with the X from the email channel and Y<X in my case)

Eventually, I will still have X individuals for the Email channel, but part of them (Y) will have also Mobile Number now.
Considering I will do that mobile numbers upload, will I be billed:

for both X+Y immediately (even before sending to anyone in the mobile channel)
for X contacts, but when I start to send to the mobile channel I will be billed for both X and those that were touched in the Mobile channel (at least once)
still just for X (as the Y will be merged under the same Contact)


Contact count is determined based on the unique Contact Key. So assuming you import your Y audience using the same Contact Key as you are using in your email channel, you will only be billed once.
